# apt showsdifferent nvidia package version than nvidia-smi

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management

Previously I had installed nvidia-384 version 384.130, which I downgraded to 384.111

nvidia-smi corroborates this:

```
nvidia-smi
```

[image]

However apt show and aptitude show still keep showing the old version

```
apt show nvidia-384
```

[image]

```
aptitude show nvidia-384
```

[image]

aptitude shows the correct currently installed. But still lists 384.130 as the current version.

I am having a lot of issue installing a deep learning environment in ubuntu 17.10 (CUDA 9.0, gcc 6, cuDNN 7). So I am trying to make everything detect the correct nvidia driver version.

Why this incoherence between package versions? Are the drivers likely incorrectly installed?

Answer (score 1):

Did you purge the old installation?

Use **locate**, or **find**, and delete specific files.

That being said, what a subtle downgrade in version!  Are you sure it will help, when most folks want the very latest drivers?!

I'm looking for the latest drivers but, I have a GTX 1080 winging its way to me, as I write - I may well have to join you in downgrading, before too long!

Can I ask, what problem have you encountered, and your certainty that downgrading is the solution?

Comment: At the end it results that the version of the driver was not the cause of my problems, which were deep within my whole ubuntu configuration.  After a complete reinstall, and now using ubuntu 16.04, I am currently using driver 384.130 with my GeForce GTX 1080 without any problems.